# How to use boost::geometry::distance with opencv cv::Point?

Tags: c++, opencv, boost, wrapper, boost-geometry

```
typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> boostPoint;
```

How to use boost::geometry::distance with opencv cv::Point without convertion to boostPoint?

```
double EuclideanDistance(const cv::Point2d &pt1, const cv::Point2d &pt2)
{
    boostPoint boostPt1(pt1.x, pt1.y);
    boostPoint boostPt2(pt2.x, pt2.y);

    double distance= boost::geometry::distance(boostPt1, boostPt2);

    return distance;
}
```

**Update:**

I tried this code, but it complaines to `x` `error: ‘x’ has not been declared`

```
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(cv::Point2d, double, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian, x, y)
```

Comment: http://www.boost.org/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/adapted/register/boost_geometry_register_point_2d.html#geometry.reference.adapted.register.boost_geometry_register_point_2d.examples

Comment: Can't you compute the distance without boost?

Comment: Do you have problem with the time it take to convert your points or you have problem with the loosing the simplicity of the code?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi to make code more elegant.

Comment: @cv_and_he can you provide example?

Comment: Did you include the required header file? Also keep in mind that you need to use this macro in the global namespace. If you still have problems, provide a minimal example (complete, even if not working and I'll try to help).

Comment: I am just eager to know if you found a good solution finally ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include the necessary header as indicated by the [doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/adapted/register/boost_geometry_register_point_2d.html#geometry.reference.adapted.register.boost_geometry_register_point_2d.header):

`#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the code more elegant, just use the proper way. Boost is not a advantage if you added to your code. Since your points are OpenCV points, compute the distance using OpenCV like this:

```
double EuclideanDistance(const cv::Point2d &pt1, const cv::Point2d &pt2)
{
    return cv::norm(pt1-pt2,cv::NORM_L2);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Since the OP need to do it in this way, I may suggest this solution: Create your own Point Class let us call it `MyPoint`. In `MyPoint` define copy constructors and conversation from and to `cv::Point`, `boostPoint`. In your code just use `YourPoint` everywhere. If you need help in implementing this just comment.

Comment: EuclideanDistance is just a simple example I need to use other boost::geometry algorithms with cv::Point.

Comment: this is not answering the ops question. boost::geometry can work with any primitives of any library via some template magic. cv::Points can be used directly without expensive data copying. question was how.